# PHP & MYSQL: Convert rows and columns to json objects

Tags: php, mysql, rows

I'm trying to get all of the rows and columns of a MYSQL table to be objects in an array so I can retrieve them via javascript.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
<?PHP
include '../sql.php';
$c = mysql_connect('localhost', $user, $pw) or die('Unable to connect to MySQL');
$s = mysql_select_db('mydb') or die('Could not select database');
$q = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM mytable') or die(mysql_error());
$a = array();

$cl = mysql_num_fields($q); 
for($i = 1; $i < $cl; $i++){
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
        foreach($r as $k => $v){
            $a[] = //something;
        }
    }
}

echo json_encode($a);
mysql_close($c);
?>
```

The object at the end should look something like this:

```
[
    {id: 1, name: 'bob', status: 'sleeping'},
    {id: 2, name: 'james', status: 'partying'},
    {id: 3, name: 'eric', status: 'reading'}
]
```

Comment: Using a deprecated API is bad practice

Comment: @Strawberry Feel free to write a solution with mysqli_connect. I'm not even a novice php developer and I need a working solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about doing it in two (I mean three!) lines?

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB;charset=utf8",'myUserName','myPassword');
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM mytable');
echo json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

PS.  Using `SELECT *` is considered bad practice.

Comment: I like short and sweet. What would be "better" than SELECT * for this example?

Comment: The code above doesn't seem to work. I tried this: $c = mysql_connect('localhost', $user, $pw) or die('Unable to connect to MySQL');
 $s = mysql_select_db('mydb') or die('Could not select database');
 $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM mytable');
 echo json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
 mysql_close($c);

Comment: See the edited post.  Skip the mysql_connect part.  Yes, short is sometimes sweet, but when you forget what you were thinking, you will no longer think so.

Comment: @ShazboticusSShazbot  Use PDO from now on!  Learn about prepared statements, and use them often.  Your welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

For mysqli json response in PHP

```
$link = mysqli_connect($servername, "$username", "$password", "$db_name", $port);
if (!$link) 
{die("MySQL connect ERROR:  " . mysqli_connect_error());}

$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
echo json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC));
@mysql_close($link);
```